# Summarise variables and add the result to the existing data frame

Tags: r

I need to group by "id_group" and find the median price, and then add this in the existing df.

`summarise` will help us finding the median price after `group_by` but how do I add this new variable to the existing df?
`mutate` might also not help as it will not `summarise` but keep repeating the entries of the grouping variable.

I tried `ave()` too but didn't help. Any other solution?

Existing data frame

```
1. id  group  value1 value2
    1.   a      10       1.2 
    2.   a      20       1.3
    3.   b      100      5.1 
    4.   b      200      5.4
```

Output needed:

```
 1. id  group  value  grp.median.values1 grp.median.values2 
    1.   a      10     10                  1.2
    2.   b      100    100                 5.1
```